# Handling mulitple async future results a le carte

Tags: c++, asynchronous, vector, future

I'm going to start by saying I have minimal experience with the C++ STL and paralleled processing. Still doing my research...

My application has a queue that tends to get large. I use asychronous `future`'s to handle these tasks a la carte (for a lack of better terms). The maximum tasks created are based on the number of available cores to the machine.

I store the `future` in a class member `vector` to prevent the task being bound to the scope of the method in which it is called from. Except, now I have the problem of dealing with the results after the task is completed. Here is a sample of my code to provide context to my question:

```
if ( ALI::WorkingTasks < CPU_HW_CONCURRENCY ) {
    std::string Task = TaskQueue.front();
    TaskQueue.pop();

    ALI::WorkingTasks++;
    ALI::AsyncTasks.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &ALI::ProcessCodecUI, this, Task));
}
```

The method that is called from `std::async`

```
bool ALI::ProcessCodecUI(std::string UIPath)
{
    // long inefficient process here

    ALI::WorkingTasks--;
    // notify condition_variable to create more tasks here
}
```

In my class definitions, this is how `ALI::AsyncTasks` is defined.

```
private:
    std::vector<std::future<bool>> AsyncTasks;
```

This is my initial implementation to get the application working at the very minimum - it works. I've done some reading on threadpools and have poked at the idea of creating my own implementation of an "a la carte" threadpool.

So my question is: How do I handle the results of the `ALI::AsyncTasks`? Every example I have seen deals with the `future` directly in the method that calls it. In my scenario, the `vector` keeps building up and the `future` never gets destroyed even after the task is completed - this creates a memory leak. I don't have anyway to self-destroy the `future` after `ProcessCodeUI()` is completed.

If I am not clear, please let me know and I will revise.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a future if you don't have a specific point in the program where you want to block while waiting for the asynchronous operation to complete.

You could achieve what you are trying to with minimal changes by using [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead of std::async then [detaching](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) the thread immediately.

```
if ( ALI::WorkingTasks < CPU_HW_CONCURRENCY ) {
    std::string Task = TaskQueue.front();
    TaskQueue.pop();

    ALI::WorkingTasks++;
    std::thread Thread (&ALI::ProcessCodecUI, this, Task);
    Thread.detach ();
}
```

Then, there is nothing left to clean up when the thread terminates. Though it would be more efficient to spawn a thread per core that pulls from a common queue.

Comment: I've considered this route but I have read that creating a new thread any time I need to run a task will be very expensive. Hence why I went the route of using `future`'s instead.

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee that std:async doesn't allocate a new thread per execution, but I you are probably correct for all common implementations. I think you should spawn a thread per core, then pull from the queue, its not much more complex, other than how you idle threads when there is not enough work to do. I imagine that is easier than trying to cleanup the futures.